# Jquery Plugin Adding Input fields dynamically, what is self vs this

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, this

So I am adding an input field once my plugin is called i.e.

```
function myPlugin ( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaults, options );
        this.init();
        this.setUpSearchField()
}

// Avoid Plugin.prototype conflicts
$.extend(myPlugin.prototype, {
        init: function () {
            if ($.isFunction(this.settings.onInit())) {
                this.settings.onInit();
            }
        },
        setUpSearchField: function () {
        //Adding Input Field to Div
        var self = this;
        this.$searchField = $("<input/>", {
            id: 'control'
        })
        .appendTo(this.element)
        .focus(function () {
            self.$searchField.val("");
        })
        }
});
```

My question when i am setting the .focus the code which works goes

```
self.$searchField.val("");
```

But if I tried to initially do

```
this.$searchField.val("");
```

I get an error saying `this.$searchField is undefined. I don't understand the difference in this scenario if anyone could explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` within the the `$.extend` block will refer to the object in the parameter, whereas `this` within the `focus` event handler will refer to the element which raised the event handler.

To stop the ambiguity between these, within the parent object `this` is stored to the `self` variable so that it can be referred to within the event handlers.

To illustrate:

```
$.extend(myPlugin.prototype, {
    // this = the object
    var self = this;

    $('#foo').focus(function () {
        // this = the #foo element
        // self = the object
    });
});
```

Comment: I gotcha now, I guess I could have also gone like this     $(this).removeAttr('style').val("");